# Stage-1 is selected by condition resolver

Tags: hive

In Hive I am performing a nested query which works all fine. However looking at the log I found something which I am interested to know. 
The job runs in 5 stages and after the completion of first stage I see a line that says `Stage-1 is selected by condition resolver`. What does this line signifies?

## Edited

Execution plan

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/dn02/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.2-1.cdh5.5.2.p0.4/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.5.2.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
OK
Time taken: 0.528 seconds
Query ID = kaliamoorthya_20170613095555_541d48fa-aa50-4346-8a26-d1e2e888e813
Total jobs = 5
Launching Job 1 out of 5
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1495648490671_93158, Tracking URL = http://ip-10-241-1-111.ec2.internal:8088/proxy/application_1495648490671_93158/
Kill Command = /dn02/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.2-1.cdh5.5.2.p0.4/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1495648490671_93158
Hadoop job information for Stage-5: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2017-06-13 09:56:19,606 Stage-5 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2017-06-13 09:56:47,705 Stage-5 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.02 sec
2017-06-13 09:57:13,588 Stage-5 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 4.07 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 4 seconds 70 msec
Ended Job = job_1495648490671_93158
Stage-1 is selected by condition resolver.
Launching Job 2 out of 5
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 12
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1495648490671_93160, Tracking URL = http://ip-10-241-1-111.ec2.internal:8088/proxy/application_1495648490671_93160/
Kill Command = /dn02/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.2-1.cdh5.5.2.p0.4/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1495648490671_93160
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 7; number of reducers: 12
2017-06-13 09:57:49,344 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2017-06-13 09:58:49,891 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 97.14 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:02,258 Stage-1 map = 10%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 125.73 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:03,287 Stage-1 map = 19%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 128.62 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:09,464 Stage-1 map = 24%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 145.15 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:12,555 Stage-1 map = 25%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 152.84 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:14,618 Stage-1 map = 36%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 157.19 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:15,650 Stage-1 map = 38%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 160.73 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:17,715 Stage-1 map = 49%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 165.49 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:18,749 Stage-1 map = 51%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 168.09 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:20,807 Stage-1 map = 53%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 172.31 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:30,103 Stage-1 map = 55%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 185.63 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:33,200 Stage-1 map = 56%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 189.14 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:36,284 Stage-1 map = 57%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 193.29 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:37,314 Stage-1 map = 67%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 194.7 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:40,410 Stage-1 map = 68%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 197.91 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:43,500 Stage-1 map = 69%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 201.48 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:46,594 Stage-1 map = 70%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 204.73 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:47,621 Stage-1 map = 80%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 205.59 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:49,676 Stage-1 map = 81%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 207.86 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:55,840 Stage-1 map = 82%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 213.56 sec
2017-06-13 09:59:58,925 Stage-1 map = 83%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 216.71 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:02,007 Stage-1 map = 84%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 219.03 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:06,120 Stage-1 map = 85%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 222.46 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:08,180 Stage-1 map = 86%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 224.28 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:09,210 Stage-1 map = 87%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 225.12 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:12,287 Stage-1 map = 88%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 227.72 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:15,362 Stage-1 map = 89%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 229.25 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:20,497 Stage-1 map = 94%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 231.42 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:24,605 Stage-1 map = 95%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 233.76 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:32,811 Stage-1 map = 96%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 236.17 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:38,975 Stage-1 map = 97%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 237.7 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:42,069 Stage-1 map = 98%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 238.48 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:48,249 Stage-1 map = 99%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 239.97 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:54,399 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 241.76 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:57,476 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 3%, Cumulative CPU 243.45 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:58,502 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 6%, Cumulative CPU 245.57 sec
2017-06-13 10:00:59,528 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 10%, Cumulative CPU 247.5 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:00,556 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 11%, Cumulative CPU 248.26 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:01,582 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 20%, Cumulative CPU 253.81 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:02,608 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 22%, Cumulative CPU 254.63 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:03,636 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 23%, Cumulative CPU 255.39 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:04,670 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 26%, Cumulative CPU 257.96 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:05,695 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 27%, Cumulative CPU 258.81 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:07,747 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 36%, Cumulative CPU 267.04 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:08,775 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 39%, Cumulative CPU 270.21 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:09,800 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 43%, Cumulative CPU 273.46 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:10,825 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 46%, Cumulative CPU 276.83 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:11,850 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 47%, Cumulative CPU 277.57 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:12,890 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 48%, Cumulative CPU 278.56 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:13,918 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 53%, Cumulative CPU 284.61 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:14,946 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 54%, Cumulative CPU 288.97 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:15,977 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 55%, Cumulative CPU 292.5 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:17,004 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 57%, Cumulative CPU 300.01 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:19,073 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 58%, Cumulative CPU 303.94 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:20,107 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 63%, Cumulative CPU 310.22 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:22,165 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 64%, Cumulative CPU 313.51 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:23,190 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 66%, Cumulative CPU 319.75 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:24,215 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 323.96 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:26,274 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 69%, Cumulative CPU 332.96 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:27,300 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 70%, Cumulative CPU 334.45 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:29,350 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 72%, Cumulative CPU 341.86 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:30,375 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 73%, Cumulative CPU 343.26 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:31,401 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 74%, Cumulative CPU 345.04 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:32,426 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 76%, Cumulative CPU 349.58 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:33,458 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 77%, Cumulative CPU 351.19 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:34,490 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 78%, Cumulative CPU 352.94 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:35,515 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 80%, Cumulative CPU 359.1 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:36,547 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 81%, Cumulative CPU 363.5 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:37,573 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 82%, Cumulative CPU 365.76 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:38,597 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 84%, Cumulative CPU 368.98 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:40,651 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 85%, Cumulative CPU 374.05 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:41,676 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 86%, Cumulative CPU 375.67 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:42,707 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 87%, Cumulative CPU 376.33 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:43,742 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 88%, Cumulative CPU 378.79 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:44,767 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 89%, Cumulative CPU 380.56 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:46,816 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 90%, Cumulative CPU 384.45 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:50,923 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 91%, Cumulative CPU 386.63 sec
2017-06-13 10:01:53,999 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 92%, Cumulative CPU 388.88 sec
2017-06-13 10:02:06,328 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 95%, Cumulative CPU 391.79 sec
2017-06-13 10:02:09,412 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 97%, Cumulative CPU 392.65 sec
2017-06-13 10:02:24,808 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 98%, Cumulative CPU 397.88 sec
2017-06-13 10:02:31,982 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 99%, Cumulative CPU 399.52 sec
2017-06-13 10:02:44,282 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 402.9 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 6 minutes 42 seconds 900 msec
Ended Job = job_1495648490671_93160
Stage-11 is selected by condition resolver.
Stage-12 is filtered out by condition resolver.
Stage-2 is filtered out by condition resolver.
Execution log at: /tmp/kaliamoorthya/kaliamoorthya_20170613095555_541d48fa-aa50-4346-8a26-d1e2e888e813.log
2017-06-13 10:02:50     Starting to launch local task to process map join;      maximum memory = 1908932608
2017-06-13 10:02:50     Dump the side-table for tag: 1 with group count: 19 into file: file:/tmp/kaliamoorthya/aa9c73be-8ece-4211-96fc-3f00131063d7/hive_2017-06-13_09-55-42_642_2976352047565338304-1/-local-10005/HashTable-Stage-6/MapJoin-mapfile01--.hashtable
2017-06-13 10:02:50     Uploaded 1 File to: file:/tmp/kaliamoorthya/aa9c73be-8ece-4211-96fc-3f00131063d7/hive_2017-06-13_09-55-42_642_2976352047565338304-1/-local-10005/HashTable-Stage-6/MapJoin-mapfile01--.hashtable (760 bytes)
2017-06-13 10:02:50     End of local task; Time Taken: 0.743 sec.
Execution completed successfully
MapredLocal task succeeded
Launching Job 4 out of 5
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1495648490671_93170, Tracking URL = http://ip-10-241-1-111.ec2.internal:8088/proxy/application_1495648490671_93170/
Kill Command = /dn02/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.2-1.cdh5.5.2.p0.4/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1495648490671_93170
Hadoop job information for Stage-6: number of mappers: 9; number of reducers: 0
2017-06-13 10:03:34,451 Stage-6 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2017-06-13 10:04:04,342 Stage-6 map = 11%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.63 sec
2017-06-13 10:04:05,370 Stage-6 map = 33%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.94 sec
2017-06-13 10:04:06,404 Stage-6 map = 44%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 6.59 sec
2017-06-13 10:04:07,436 Stage-6 map = 67%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 10.02 sec
2017-06-13 10:04:08,471 Stage-6 map = 78%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 11.71 sec
2017-06-13 10:04:10,532 Stage-6 map = 89%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 13.37 sec
2017-06-13 10:04:13,659 Stage-6 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 15.05 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 15 seconds 50 msec
Ended Job = job_1495648490671_93170
Moving data to: hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/alexraj_directplus.db/directplus_product_vailability_result
Table alexraj_directplus.directplus_product_vailability_result stats: [numFiles=9, numRows=0, totalSize=0, rawDataSize=0]
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-5: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 4.07 sec   HDFS Read: 10779 HDFS Write: 593 SUCCESS
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 7  Reduce: 12   Cumulative CPU: 402.9 sec   HDFS Read: 748687131 HDFS Write: 1152 SUCCESS
Stage-Stage-6: Map: 9   Cumulative CPU: 15.05 sec   HDFS Read: 43782 HDFS Write: 738 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 7 minutes 2 seconds 20 msec
OK
Time taken: 514.257 seconds
```

Comment: Please add the full execution plan

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, I have updated the question based on your request.

Comment: Thanks, but the request was for the execution plan (`explain select ...`)